# Using .NET version 4.7.2 alongisde other versions

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have version 8.0.100 installed as I can see from `dotnet --list-sdks`.

I am working on a project with `TargetFrameworkVersion` `v4.7.2`.
When I build with Visual Studio it works fine, but when I build with `dotnet build` I get many errors.

I thought maybe because the build command is using v8. I am trying to install v4.7.2 so that
I can build from terminal as well, but I am not really able to understand how from the MS documentation and googling.

I used the offline installer I found on MS and it ran successfully, but I still don't see it on the list SDKs command.

I also tried doing `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 4.7.2` and then `dotnet restore` but it just says that 4.7.2 is not installed. And after I created the global.json, when I just do `dotnet build`, it says 4.7.2 is not installed even though I did it using the offline installer.

Based on some research, I found out that  v4.7.2 is installed at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET`. But it looks very different to the v8 SDK which is installed at `C:\Program Files\dotnet`.

I want to be able to build from terminal, since a lot of tools I am looking into require me to be able to build from terminal. I am fairly new to dotnet and do not know a lot about the environment yet. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you install the [developer pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net472-developer-pack-offline-installer)? Because the runtime is not sufficient to build a .NET Framework app, you need the SDK too.

Comment: Yes, I installed that developer pack.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: The errors are related to the msbuild visual studio uses vs msbuild the terminal command uses. For example, `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" was not found`. But when building with VS, the path is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets`. 
And when I explicitly make the dotnet command point to the location of the VS path for that particular file, errors definitely related to version differences.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I'm not expecting a target called `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office` (you know, VSTO, aka Visual Studio Tools for Office) to work without Visual Studio. Maybe you should instead look at the Visual Studio Build Tools to use VS from the command line.

Comment: Okay it is starting to make some sense to me now.
`& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"` works for me. It builds successfully.
But, `& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\dotnet\net8.0\runtime\dotnet.exe" build`  and  `& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\dotnet\net8.0\runtime\dotnet.exe" test`  don't work because it says that no .net sdk exists. So, VS uses separate binaries for each dotnet command?

Comment: The `dotnet` command line tool is for **.NET Core** only - .NET Core 1.x, 2.x, 3.x and .NET 5 and up. It does **not** support the "old" legacy/classic **.NET** framework - with versions up to v4.8.1 - that needs to be handled by using MSBuild instead

Comment: Ahh, I see.. I couldn't figure that out from all the different things I read :P Thanks for that. You saved me some time!